# I need to find a single word (noun) for a person who acts as a " work-stopper"

Tags: single-word-requests

I need to find a word (noun) for a person who acts as a "work-stopper" and creates hurdles for others so that the work cannot be completed.
For example, some government officials force people to follow long bureaucratic procedures to create delays or put-off the worker (use of delay-tactics).

Example sentence:
David is a ...

Comment: Single word requests should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: Example could be, "David is a hurdle-creator". I need a good replacement of "hurdle-creator".

Comment: Sounds like a bottleneck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider ***obstructionist***:

> someone who systematically obstructs some action that others want to take
>   <sub>[Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/obstructionist)</sub>

An example of its use:

> The self-absorbed ***obstructionist*** may be a perfectionist, a slow-moving tortoise, an indecisive type, or a complete slacker.
>   <sub>[The Complete Idiot's Guide to Coping with Difficult People](https://books.google.com/books?id=DUHD9FglevUC&pg=PA243&dq=obstructionist&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_4KzUs87nAhVrGDQIHe6gCOIQuwUwAnoECAMQBw#v=onepage&q=obstructionist&f=false)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The term "bureaucrat" is usually used as such.  Stonewaller or impeder might also work.

Comment: Please add references for the meanings of those words.

Comment: While a bureaucrat might have this effect, it's not specifically what they're intending to do.

Comment: "Stonewaller" and "impeder"  do convey the meaning, but appear very informal.

Comment: @Barmar - How about "manager"?

Answer (score 0):

**Liability**

It means, someone who is a cost to proceedings, rather than being an asset.

Example: ‘David is a liability - he slows everything down and gets in the way all the time.’

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/liability